# Angularjs ngRoute not routing as it should

Tags: angularjs, routes, ngroute

first of all sorry if I write with bad grammar/expressions, my english is not the best.

Well, I'm trying to show a product via ID, for this I'm sending this ID from a list of products with this url: `localhost/products/product/:ID` and I'm receiving `GET http://localhost/products/product/101 404 (Not Found)`(the 101 is an example).

If I go to `http://localhost/products/product.html` it is changed for `http://localhost` but is not redirected, just change the url in the address bar

Here is my code

```
 var app = angular.module('AppMarketApp', ['ngRoute']);
  app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled:true,
    requireBase: false});
  $routeProvider
    .when("/products/product/:codProd", {
      templateUrl: '../js/product/appInfo.html',
      controller: 'Controller'
    })
   .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});;
 });
app.controller("Controller",['$scope','$http', '$routeParams', function($scope,$http, $routeParams){
        $scope.row = {};
        var codProd= $routeParams.codProd;
        //some extra code here.
```

**directive**

```
app.directive('appInfo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '../js/product/appInfo.html'
  };
});
```

and **html**

```
<body ng-app="AppMarketApp" ng-controller="Controller">
  <div class="page" style="">
    <div class="content-showproduct">
      <div class="product" ng-view>
        <app-info info="arts"></app-info>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="../js/product/Controller.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/product/appInfo.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any ideas? if you guys need some extra info let me know.

In addition, I think that I have some bad code in the HTML file, more specifically here

```
<div class="product" ng-view>
    <app-info info="arts"></app-info>
</div>
```

I dont know if it will work well after routing. Without ng-view in others files works well. But is not important right now.

Comment: have you set the base url ?

Comment: I was misunderstanding how ngRoute works. I already fixed it, I was trying to go to a different url. e.g:  from .../index.html to .../product.html/101, and that is not how it works, I have to stay in the same .html file.

Comment: You can directly go to the page too, example if you share the link `product/101` with someone...